# Dúvidas de como pegar valores de linhas dentro de um aquivo em C de forma aleatória

Tags: c

Galera, estou criando um jogo chamado "rode a roda",eu tenho dúvida em uma parte do código, onde eu preciso pegar palavras dentro de um arquivo de forma aleatória. O meu arquivo estar dessa maneira que colocarei abaixo:
vegetal 2 alface alcega
cozinha 2 colher fogao
automovel 2 embreagem freio

Quando eu uso o fscanf para ler o arquivo eu só consigo traze o primeiro de cada linha. O que eu precisava fazer era pegar uma palavra de forma aleatória para printar para o usuário como PISTA. O que exatamente não estou conseguindo.

Eu gostaria de conseguir pegar de forma aleatória  cada palavra de cada coluna. O meu código não apresenta erro na hora de compilar, mas não consigo pegar as palavras de dentro do arquivo de forma aleatoria.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>



 typedef struct frase{
    char pista[17];
    int qtd;
    char vetpalavras[3][17];
 }Frase;
main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int i;
        Frase lista;
    FILE *palavra;
    palavra = fopen("PALAVRAS.dat","r");

    if(palavra == NULL){
        printf("Erro na abertura!!");
        return 0;
    }

        fscanf(palavra,"%s %d %s ", lista.pista, &lista.qtd,lista.vetpalavras);
        printf(" A palavra estar associada com: %s  \n",lista.pista);
        printf("Palavra: %s \n ",lista.vetpalavras );

        fclose(palavra);





    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Não entendi o layout de seu arquivo PALAVRAS.DAT, talvez você tenha copiado de algum lugar e não tenha prestado atenção no resultado da cópia.

Comment: Me desculpe.Vegetal 2 ACELGA ALFACE 
Automóvel 3 MOTOR EMBREAGEM ESCAPAMENTO
Cozinha 3 PRATO PANELA FOGÃO
Réptil 1 JARARACA  
Mamífero 2 BALEIA MACACO

Comment: Não sei se entendi corretamente, mas creio que na leitura de vetpalavras você deve ler apenas a quantidade de palavras existentes, lida na variável qtd. Faça um loop para tal leitura. Talvez seja mais fácil você ler a linha inteira com um getline e depois utilizar um sscanf para ler o que existe na linha.

Comment: Troque: fscanf(palavra,"%s %d %s ", &pista.pista, &pista.qtd, &pista.vetpalavras); por: fscanf(palavra,"%s %d %s ",pista.pista, &pista.qtd); for (i=0; i<qtd; i++) fscanf(palavra," %s", pista.vetpalavras[i]);

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o quer dizer com "conseguir pegar um valor de uma linha de forma aleatória".

Comment: Por exemplo, imagine que meu arquivo tenha 5 linhas. Na linha 1 tem um valor 1000 do tipo inteiro. na linha 2 um valor 2000 do tipo inteiro, isso para todas as linhas. tipo:
100
200
300
400
500
Quando executar o programa a 1  vez preciso que ele pega um valor de uma linha, quando executar outra vez, preciso que pegue outro valor de outra linha. Espero ter explicado melhor. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Você conseguirá a cada leitura recuperar um registro diferente com o uso da função fseek com o offset sendo gerado a partir de um número aleatório (vide a função rand) dentre a quantidade de registros existentes. Com esta abordagem podem ocorrer repetição de linhas anteriormente lidas o que não está claro se seria uma situação permitida ou não em seu projeto.

Comment: Sim é permitido repetição. Cara sem querer me aproveitar de você, como seria isso com a função rand? Eu sou novo na área e estou meio perdido e com dificuldades, ainda no primeiro semestre da faculdade, mas quero aprender.

Comment: Veja um exemplo em: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: Olha, estou fazendo dessa maneira, não conseguir pegar outra linha. Acho que essa seria a primeira parte.

# include <stdio.h>


main(){
 
 float grana;

FILE *premio;
premio = fopen("PREMIOS.DAT","r");
 fseek(premio, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fscanf(premio,"%f", &grana);
        printf("Premio: %f", grana);
}

Comment: Você está fazendo uma única leitura, talvez você quisesse que a leitura estivesse em um loop, além disso na função fseek você fixou o offset como zero, desta forma irá sempre pegar a partir do início do arquivo.

Comment: Faça uma nova pergunta postando a definição de seu arquivo, pelo menos um exemplo de registro, as struct utilizadas e o código de seu programa. Esta maneira de perguntas e respostas não é recomendada para o StackOverflow. Veja o tour [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour].

Comment: Perdão, mas não posso fazer mais perguntas.

Comment: Então siga a recomendação do Maniero: edite sua pergunta e poste todos os dados relevantes, seu código, o que está dando errado e qual o resultado esperado.

Comment: A comunidade, peço desculpa, é a primeira vez que faço uma pergunta. Preciso realmente dar uma estuda sobre o StackOverflow. Segundo as recomendações dos amigos acima. Editei minha pergunta e espero ser compreendido e ter conseguido passar minha dúvida de forma clara. Obrigado a todos.